# Copying char array and printing hex from copied array gives error

Tags: c

I was trying a basic program to copy elements form one array to another. The source array is having more elements. While copying elements from source to destination i only copy few elements from source array.

My source array contains some hex value.

As i am printing the destination array in hex form the last element is different. i.e that elements unknowingly adds up `ffffff`

Here is the sample program

```
void String_Copy(char *src, char *dest, int length)
{
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char firstStr[] = {0x01,0x03,0x02,0x13,0x88,0xB5,0x12};
    char secStr[5];

    String_Copy(firstStr,secStr,5);

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%02x ",secStr[i]);
    }

}
```

Here i want to copy only five elements and print the output.

> > Expected Output: 01 03 02 13 88
> >
> > Getting Output: 01 03 02 13 ffffff88

Where are these `ffffff` are coming from???

[image]

What is happening behind the scene?????

Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay will keep in mind about that(thanks).

Comment: Make your data type of char as unsigned char and print the array?

Comment: yes its working after using unsigned and i got why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the result of *sign-extending*. Your platform obviously has a **signed** `char` type, so you already have implementation defined behavior in your initialization:

```
char firstStr[] = {0x01,0x03,0x02,0x13,0x88,0xB5,0x12};
```

`0x88` can't be represented in your `char` type, probably, the maximum value would be `0x7f`. The result of a conversion to a *signed* type is implementation-defined if the type can't represent the value. In your case, it results in some negative number.

Now, your argument to `printf()` is subject to *integer promotion rules*, it's converted to an `int`. For a negative number, this means adding `1` bits in the extra places, that's why you see a bunch of `0xf` hex digits when trying to print this as an unsigned. This is btw not well-defined either, `%x` expects an `unsigned`, but you give it a *signed* value.

The simplest solution would be to just use `unsigned char` everywhere. Also, change the format string to `%02hhx` to tell `printf()` it's just an unsigned **char**, not an unsigned **int**.